# Finding the inverse function

Tags: derivatives, inverse

The question is to find the inverse function of

$$f(x)=x-(2\sqrt{x})+1$$

I first  found that the domain of definition is $\,x\ge 0$

Then studied the variation of the function and it is decreasing between $0$ and $1$ and increasing otherwise. Thus there are $2$ inverse functions to be found.
 
How can I find them. Any hints?

Comment: how do you usualy find inverse??? $y=x-2\sqrt{x}+1$ and then solve for $x$.. Have you done that?

Comment: I did but the problem is with the sqrt(x)

Comment: How to get rid of it

Comment: substitute $t=\sqrt{x}$

Comment: if you want to get rid of "root" in "square root" you have to "Square" it.....

Comment: Ok thanks then I solve t^2-2t+1-y=0. Right?

Comment: yes. Second step is to have t appear just once

Comment: I got the inverse function is the same as the initial function.is this true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $y = x-2\sqrt{x}+1 = (\sqrt{x}-1)^2$

$x = (1\pm\sqrt{y})^2=1 \pm 2\sqrt{y} + y$

So $f^{-1}(x)=x\pm2\sqrt{x}+1$

Specifically $f^{-1}(x) = x+2\sqrt{x}+1$ when $x\ge1$ and $f^{-1}(x) = x-2\sqrt{x}+1$ when $0\le x\le1$.